# React Native + Firebase one time read doesn't resolve when logged in

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an app with TypeScript + Firebase. I've followed this website to set it up: `https://rnfirebase.io`. After I finished with authentication I wanted to get a value from the real time database. However making the request doesn't resolve. I've also put it in the await version however that didn't resolve either.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";
import { firebase } from "@react-native-firebase/database";
import { REALTIME_DATABASE_ENV } from "react-native-dotenv";

const TestPage = () => {

    useEffect(() => {
        const reference = firebase
            .app()
            .database(REALTIME_DATABASE_ENV)
            .ref("particularities/")
            .once("value")
            .then((snapshot) => {
                console.log(`snapshot: ${snapshot.val()}`);
                //expected result:
                // {
                //  sickness: {
                //      label: "Sickness",
                //  },
                //  allergic: {
                //      label: "Allergic",
                //  },
                // };
            })
            .catch((e: unknown) => {
                console.log(`catch: ${e}`);
            });
    }, []);

    return (
        <Text>Test page</Text>
    );
};

export default TestPage;
```

The rules that are applied to the real time database:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false,
    // ...
    "particularities": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true,
    },
  }
}
```

Thing we found: logging out of the app does resolve all the requests made. Testing while logged in and all rules set to public gives the same result as before with the promise not resolving

Comment: I see you have a `console.log` in the `then` and another one in the `catch`. Which of these two (if any) shows up in your output?

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation here is how you can read the data once.

https://rnfirebase.io/database/usage#one-time-read

You don't need to pass database ref other than an 'us-central1'

```
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';

database()
  .ref('particularities/')
  .once('value')
  .then(snapshot => {
    console.log('Data: ', snapshot.val());
  })
  .catch((e: unknown) => {
    console.log(`catch: ${e}`);
  });
```